# The Integrability of the Nth composite for the Riemann integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Generally we can't say " if both $g$ and $f$ are Riemann integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ then
the $g \circ f$ is Riemann integrable."
So more considering the specific case, Is the $f^n(x) (=f \circ f\ \circ ... \circ f)$ Riemann integrable ? (Here the $f$ is a Riemann integrable)

In my thought, it looks false to me. But I couldn't find any counter-examples.

Then Is that true statement?

p.s.) If it is true, please suggest me some proof about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an example of two Riemann integrable functions $f,g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $f \circ g$ us not Riemann integrable, define a new function $h : [0,2]\to[0,2]$  as
$$
h(x) := \begin{cases}
f(x)+1,\quad& 0 \le x \le 1,
\\
g(x-1),\quad& 1 < x \le 2 .
\end{cases}
$$
Then $h$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,2]$, but $h \circ h$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,2]$.